# Why is byte compiler issuing a warning on one of these 2 de Morgan equivalent expressions?

Tags: byte-compilation, warning

Assuming that the symbol foo is not defined nor declared with a defvar or let form, the following code generates a byte-compiler warning in Emacs 26.3 and 27.2:

```lisp
(defun f-or ()
  "Use or."
  (when (or (null (boundp 'foo))
            (null foo))  ;=> ``Warning: reference to free variable ‘foo’``
    (message "foo is not set")))
```

However, the following, longer, but de Morgan equivalent code does **not** generate a byte-compiler warning:

```lisp
(defun f-and ()
  "Use and."
  (when (null (and (boundp 'foo)
                  foo))         ; no warning here!
    (message "foo is not set")))
```

Replacing `null` for its alias `not`, using `(unless X ...)` instead of `(when (not X) ...` changes nothing, as expected.

**Question:** Why does Emacs byte-compiler generate a warning for the expression using the `or` form but not for the expression using the `and` form?  Should this be reported as a byte compiler improvement request to *not* generate this invalid warning in both cases?

Comment: Because that's the way the byte-compiler is coded? ;-) BTW, `(when (null X)...)` is equivalent to `(unless X ...)`.

Comment: @Drew I used this example instead of unless because in my code, these are part of a longer boolean expression.  I just extracted the relevant part.  If the byte compiler is coded that way then wouldn't you think this applies as an improvement request to the byte compiler warning generation part?

Comment: /me thinks the warning is valid: there is a reference to a free variable in each case. The problem is the *absence* of the warning in the `and` case.

Comment: @NickD The absence of a warning in the `and` case is intentional, forms the basis of the `bound-and-true-p` macro, and also applies to `fboundp`. Checking whether a variable or function is defined and conditionally using it in that case is quite a common pattern in Elisp, especially for achieving forward/backward compatibility, so the byte-compiler is right not to complain in such cases. Any shortcomings of this feature should be reported via `M-x report-emacs-bug`, if they haven't already been.

Comment: My comment was directed towards the OP's "invalid warning" characterization.  I just wanted to point out that the warning is valid in both cases - OTOH, describing its absence as a "problem" was ill-informed on my part. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @NickD I believe the warning is invalid *because* the code checks for the symbol to be bound *before* it tries to evaluate it.  Both the ``or`` and the ``and`` forms are short-circuiting forms and will not evaluate more once the condition is met.  So in both my code examples the unbound symbols would not be evaluated.  If it was, running the code would trigger an error. @Basil, I will report this problem as a bug report later today unless I found it was already reported.

Comment: I reported this bug as https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=49749

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After submitting a [bug report for this that was rejected](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=49749) I better understand the overall intent of the byte compiler as it was best described by Lars Ingebrigtsen in his closing remark:

> "The issue isn't that the compiler warning is wrong -- it's correct;
> but we suppress it in very particular situations where it'll obviously
> not lead to any problems."

The byte-compiler is inconsistent in its warning generation but that's an implementation decision.

- In both scenarios above the code will run without errors but in both case the `foo` symbol is unbound (a free variable) and a warning reporting it as a free variable is not incorrect.
- The implementers of the byte-compiler have chosen to inhibit the warning in valid code scenarios that are often seen, but not all.
- That's a implementation decision as valid as any other that I hope this question/answer ticket will clarify for others that might run into this.

Now the easy way out to prevent this byte-compiler warning is to place a `(defvar foo)` form above the code, something I did not mention before because I wanted to concentrate on the warning generation aspect.   The loop is closed.